# Is it possible to pause a program running under gdb to alter a breakpoint that hasn't been hit or add a new one?

Tags: debugging, gdb

I have a long running program that takes a while to reach a breakpoint. Based on another instance of gdb, I realize I want to stop somewhere earlier to inspect something and so I would like to pause a gdb which is on its way to a breakpoint, insert another breakpoint, and resume it..if I do Ctrl+C that interrupts my program and i have to restart from the beginning. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if I do Ctrl+C that interrupts my program and i have to restart from the beginning

It does not (normally) interrupt your program, it should only interrupt the GDB itself. If you `continue` from that point, the program will continue *without* receiving `SIGINT`.

Example:

```
int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  while (1) {
    sleep(1);
    i += 1;
  }
}

gdb ./a.out
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00007ffff7b03b10 in __nanosleep_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7b03b10 in __nanosleep_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
#1  0x00007ffff7b039a0 in __sleep (seconds=<optimized out>) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sleep.c:138
#2  0x0000000000400542 in main () at t.c:5
(gdb) fr 2
#2  0x0000000000400542 in main () at t.c:5
5       sleep(1);
(gdb) print i
$1 = 1
(gdb) c
Continuing.
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00007ffff7b03b10 in __nanosleep_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7b03b10 in __nanosleep_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
#1  0x00007ffff7b039a0 in __sleep (seconds=<optimized out>) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sleep.c:138
#2  0x0000000000400542 in main () at t.c:5
(gdb) fr 2
#2  0x0000000000400542 in main () at t.c:5
5       sleep(1);
(gdb) print i
$2 = 4
(gdb) q
```

Comment: You are right about that, I think I confused myself because I was getting Bus Errors when recompiling my binary with changes and debugging in another instance of gdb while a gdb was running on the former overwritten binary and I must have mixed this up with my continuous interrupt signals. Thanks